# Zend 2 Hostname Validator for IDN Domains

Tags: php, zend-framework2, hostname

I can register `töst.tv` as a domain in other words it is a valid domain name.

The Zend 2 Hostname Validator will return false on following example:

```
// create hostname validator
$oHostnameValidator = new \Zend\Validator\Hostname(array(
    'allow' => \Zend\Validator\Hostname::ALLOW_DNS,
    'useIdnCheck' => true,
    'useTldCheck' => false,
));

if(!$oHostnameValidator->isValid('töst.tv')) // isValid returns false
{
    print_r($oHostnameValidator->getMessages());
}
```

`getMessages` will return:

```
Array
(
    [hostnameInvalidHostnameSchema] =&gt; Die Eingabe scheint ein DNS Hostname zu sein, passt aber ...
    [hostnameInvalidLocalName] =&gt; Die Eingabe scheint kein g&#xFC;ltiger lokaler Netzerkname zu...
)
```

I see that `protected $validIdns` does not include the tld `tv` (in class `Zend\Validator\Hostname`)

Is there a way to (update-safe) inject current valid idn checks into some tlds in the zend hostname validator?

Or is this a bug which should be reported?

**Edit**

i just extended the hostname validator (thanks to **Wilt**)

```
<?php

namespace yourNamespace;

class Hostname extends \Zend\Validator\Hostname
{
    /**
     * Sets validator options.
     *
     * @param int  $allow       OPTIONAL Set what types of hostname to allow (default ALLOW_DNS)
     * @param bool $useIdnCheck OPTIONAL Set whether IDN domains are validated (default true)
     * @param bool $useTldCheck Set whether the TLD element of a hostname is validated (default true)
     * @param Ip   $ipValidator OPTIONAL
     * @see http://www.iana.org/cctld/specifications-policies-cctlds-01apr02.htm  Technical Specifications for ccTLDs
     */
    public function __construct($options = array())
    {
        // call parent construct
        parent::__construct($options);

        // inject valid idns
        $this->_injectValidIDNs();
    }

    /**
     * inject new valid idns - use first DE validation as default (until we get the specified correct ones ...)
     */
    protected function _injectValidIDNs()
    {
        // inject TV validation
        if(!isset($this->validIdns['TV']))
        {
            $this->validIdns['TV'] = array(
                1 => array_values($this->validIdns['DE'])[0],
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's a valid hostname and the hostname validator returns false, it's a bug.  Update-safe way is probably sub-classing Zend\Validator\Hostname and using your own override, that is usually how things were done in ZF1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an issue on GitHub and make a pull request for the `Zend\Validator\Hostname` class in which you add the value that according to you should be also inside the [`$validIdns`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/Hostname.php#L1187) array.

Otherwise you can also extend the existing class in your project and overwrite the existing [`$validIdns`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/Hostname.php#L1187) value with your custom one:

```
<?php

namespace My\Validator;

class HostName extends \Zend\Validator\Hostname
{
    protected $validIdns = [
        //...your custom value for TV + existing ones...
    ]
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
$oHostnameValidator = new \My\Validator\Hostname(array(
    'allow' => \My\Validator\Hostname::ALLOW_DNS,
    'useIdnCheck' => true,
    'useTldCheck' => false,
));
```